# C# checkbox header issue when scroll the bar

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have a datagridview with multiple column and I had create a custom checkbox in one of the column header . Since I want to fix the checkbox header in the column when i scroll the bar, so i create 'scroll'event to handle it.

```
    private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll)
        {
            chbx.Location = new Point(chbx.Location.X - (e.NewValue - e.OldValue), chbx.Location.Y);
        }
        if (chbx.Location.X < dataGridView1.Location.X)
        {
            chbx.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            chbx.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

It's works (Picture 1). However, when i click the refresh button(data in gridview refresh) and i scroll the bar again, it comes with the problem below(Picture2).

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/banl5.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yarI.png).

```
    private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        SetupDGV();
    }


    private void SetupDGV()
    {            
        ///.....
        chbx = new CheckBox();

        Point headerCellLocation = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true).Location;

        chbx.Name = "enableCHBX";
        chbx.Location = new Point(headerCellLocation.X + 60, headerCellLocation.Y + 8);
        chbx.BackColor = Color.White;
        chbx.Size = new Size(15, 15);

        // Assign Click event to the Header CheckBox.
        cbx.Click += new EventHandler(chbxEnable_Click);
        dataGridView1.Controls.Add(chbx);
    }
```

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: Does the number of Columns Change or the width of the Grid change? Is it creating a duplicate checkbox because you aren't wiping the `dataGridView1.Controls` collection and removing the `chkbx` you have created?

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the `dataGridView1_Scroll` Event Handler.

Instead I have used the `Paint` event using: `this.dataGridView1.Paint += this.Handle_Paint;`

Inside the `Paint Event Handler` I have the following code:

```
private void Handle_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //// Get the header cell
    var cell = this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell;

    //// Get the Location
    var headerCellLocation = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, true).Location;
    
    //// Get the Horizontal Scrolling Offset (if the User has scrolled)
    var scrollOffset = this.dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset;

    //// Get the Cell width (minus) the checkbox width (minus) any scrolling there is
    var widthVal = cell.Size.Width - this.chbx.Size.Width - scrollOffset;

    //// Get 1/4 of the Cells height (so the checkbox sits in the center)
    var quarterCellHeight = cell.Size.Height / 4;

    //// Calculate the new Location for the Checkbox
    var newLocation = new Point(headerCellLocation.X + widthVal, headerCellLocation.Y + quarterCellHeight);

    //// Update the Location
    this.chbx.Location = newLocation;
}
```

I have also added the following `if` statement inside of the `SetupDGV` method:

```
if (this.dataGridView1.Controls.Contains(this.chbx))
{
    this.dataGridView1.Controls.Remove(this.chbx); //// Remove so we don't have a duplicate
}
```

Which ensures we won't create a duplicate checkbox inside of the dataGridView when we refresh the Data for the grid.

Here is a quick little video of the result:
https://gyazo.com/e544b38b1ca065bb16e4f279fc5aa24e